# Use Django's generic date based views to display multiple querysets

Tags: django, django-views

I'd like to use Django's [class-based generic date views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/generic-date-based/) to display lists of several models from the particular day/month/year (e.g., all Tweets from 10 Nov, all Photos from 10 Nov) but am not sure of the best approach.

I've started trying to add querysets, in addition to the view's main one, in `get_context_data()` but am tying myself in knots with trying to replicate the way the views add the date-based filtering. It seems so tied in to `self.queryset` that it's hard to use for other ad-hoc querysets. Or have I missed something?

Comment: The date based CBVs are probably not very well suited to multiple querysets. You'll probably end up with easier-to-understand, more maintainable code if you write your own function based view, or override a more generic class based view.

Comment: Thanks Alasdair... I was hoping there was something obvious I'd missed in the date-based CBVs, but I guess not.